# How to Apply a CssClass to a series of similar objects with a different ID

Tags: asp.net, html, user-interface, css

I have a large application in which I have lots of Submit - Delete - Cancel - Add and .. buttons. All of them use a same `.Button` CssClass.

I decided to reach the interface so that I want to differise buttons interface.

How to Apply a CSSClass to a series of similar objects with a different ID

I should Have similar Delete / Submit / Cancel or ... Button interface all over the application

All of the Delete button id are btnDelete and the same for the rest. (btnSubmit - btnCancel ...)

Note that they are Asp control so that only the last part of their name are btnDelete or ... and before Name, you have a client ID like (MainPage_MainControl_TheSimpleForm_btnDelete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pure CSS way to do this would be a [substring selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings):

```
[id$="btnDelete"] { /* delete button styles */ }
[id$="btnSubmit"] { /* submit button styles */ }
[id$="btnCancel"] { /* cancel button styles */ }
```

These match any elements with an `id` attribute which ends in `btnDelete`, `btnSubmit` and `btnCancel` respectively.  Unfortunately these are not supported by IE8 so you'd need to have a jQuery fallback.

Answer (score 2):

Use the common class you declared:

```
.Button {
  /* applies to all buttons */
}
```

If you want to select a group buttons, you  can add more styles separated by space.

```
<button class="Button AddButton" id="AddButton1">Add</Button>
```

CSS

```
.AddButton {
  /* only applies to add buttons */
}
```

**Edit:**

After clarification we need to add classes without changing the original HTML. How about looping over the elements and assign an additional class depending on the id.

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var btn = buttons[i];
    if (btn.id.indexOf('btnAdd') > 0) {
       btn.className = btn.className + ' ButtonAdd'; // the space is important
    } else if (btn.id.indexOf('btnDelete') > 0) {
       btn.className = btn.className + ' ButtonDelete'; // the space is important
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't add something in the code because of the large amount of the items. And also it's not limited to buttons only. suggest another solution

Comment: and @Bob, I think it will work cause it makes sense, but do you know any css hack? like using  type selectors or what ever else? I don't think that using script will be a good Idea, I'd rather to have a replace all in all over the project instead of using this runtime script

Comment: I can't think of any such hack. Perhaps someone smarter than me... sorry.

Answer (score 2):

And if you need to do this programatically at runtime, you could always use JQuery and the [AddClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method.  To handle partial ID match, take a look at the [Attribute Contains documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/)

```
$('[ID*="btnDelete"]').AddClass("newCSSClassToAdd")
```

Comment: it won't work for me because `.Button` is general and then `newCSSClassToAdd` will added to all of them. Id addition Ican't get the ID of allll buttons because they are in different pages

Comment: Choices.  For runtime, you could also do a partial ID search in JQuery assuming your names at least follow convention.  If it's a one-time design time, you may be stuck with WinGrep and search/replace with a regex to imbed a new class that way.

Comment: I'd write an answer for martin that used your suggested plan. take a look please

Comment: (See edits above.  Partial Attribute Selector sounds like what you are looking for).

Comment: The partial attribute selector only matches ids which *begin* with `btnDelete`